# Reference Books on Cryptography

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cryptography

I successfully ended the book **Elementary Number Theory** by *David M. Burton*. It is a great book on Number Theory and History of Number Theory. Specially, I loved the concise chapter on **Cryptography**. Now, I am pretty interested to continue my study in Cryptography.
Which books or websites should I read to learn more on Cryptography, if there is more math of it?

Comment: Just in case: you're already aware that we have a [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: In any event, you will want to see [Schneier's stuff](http://www.schneier.com/books.html)...

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks, that [crypto.SE] is first reference for me.

Comment: @J.M. Some of those book titles are hilarious.

Comment: Just a note, [we don't want "book list" questions](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1) on crypto.SE, they will get closed. (We might do a [chat session](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/97/crypto-chatcasts) about this topic, though.)

Comment: @Paŭlo: thanks for the info; I was tempted to flag this for migration, but held back. Apparently it was a good call. :)

Comment: @Paŭlo: My main aim of asking this question is not to get a list of some books, but actually some references that I could proceed my learnings. Prof. Burton had already given a list of some good reference texts in book's appendices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cryptography is a rapidly changing subject at its frontier. However, though it dates from 1997 the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) by A. Menezes, P. van Oorschot, and S. Vanstone, has nice surveys of many topics related to cryptography.

Comment: HAC This is outdated and can contain misleading claims.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction to Modern Cryptography** by *J.Katz* and *Y.Lindell* (CRC Press) is a nice book to start formal cryptography. For a more advanced reader, **Foundations of Cryptography** by *Oded Goldreich* can be handy.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading **Hoffstein, Pipher, Silverman-*An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography 2nd*** and also like from what I've read of **Trappe, Washington-*introduction to cryptography with coding theory 2nd***. I have 85 books that I looked through briefly and these were the two best. The authors actually explain the theory intelligently because they actually understand the topics. The other books I looked at would explain things that were obvious (Paar, Pelzl) or hid the fact that they didn't understand everything by putting undefined meaningless symbols in a function.

Answer (score 0):

This question was duplicated here: [References for intermediate cryptography](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147611/references-for-intermediate-cryptography)

So, I will give a more recent answer. I highly recommend the book Serious Cryptography: A Practical Introduction to Modern Encryption Kindle
by Jean-Philippe Aumasson. This book is very beginner friendly.