# Cryptography books?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cryptography

Not sure if this is the correct place to post. If not, maybe someone knows where I should go :)

I am curious about cryptography and have taken some related courses through my studies. However I was wondering if anyone have any reccommendations for books on the topic. I am not looking for textbooks, but rather "fun" books that do contain mathematical explanations. Perhaps recreational mathematics is a good description. I have looked at *The Code Book* by *Simon Singh* and *The Code Breakers* by *David Kahn*.

In advance: thank you :)

Comment: For mathematical references, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71420/reference-books-on-cryptography?rq=1). For "fun" books, the two books you have named are sufficient, I suppose?

Comment: Elonka Dunin & Klaus Schmeh, *Codebreaking: A Practical Guide* looks like fun (but I haven't read it).

Comment: Decrypted Secrets
Methods and Maxims
of Cryptology